# Python Fire hyphen vs underscore

Tags: python, python-fire

The python package `Fire` is very useful for launching python scripts from command line. One common thing is to have arguments made of multiple words, for instance name of cat that can be written in 3 commons way :

- nameofcat
- name_of_cat
- name-of-cat

While the first one is compatible with pretty much everything, the second one should be avoided in bash ([Should command line options in POSIX-style operating systems be underscore style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253679/should-command-line-options-in-posix-style-operating-systems-be-underscore-style)) and the third one in python ([Why does python disallow usage of hyphens within function and variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-does-python-disallow-usage-of-hyphens-within-function-and-variable-names)).

The problem here is that by default fire will take arguments name from the python code, which means that if my python code looks like this:

script.py:

```
import fire
def main(name_of_cat='Steve'):
    print(f'The name of the cast is {name_of_cat}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(main)
```

then to call it from the command line (or from a bash script), one would do

```
python script.py --name_of_cat Bob
```

This is the way I'm using it at the moment, but this feels suboptimal. Any idea on what the best practice is here ?

PS : `python script.py --name-of-cat Bob` would be impossible since python can't have hyphen in variable names.

Comment: Not sure about **fire** but [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#dest) automatically converts dashes to underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it works with either hyphens or underscores, possibly because of [this line of code](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/c3789064e2e161992e3c5a23eb0c47b66072707f/fire/completion.py#L390). Using your script:

```bsh
> python .\script.py --name_of_cat Bob
The name of the cast is Bob
> python .\script.py --name-of-cat Bob
The name of the cast is Bob
```

This is also noted [here](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/878b8d86f488ef2606cffdf58297dd2781708316/docs/guide.md) in the Fire docs:

> To instantiate a `Building` and then run the `climb_stairs` function, the following commands are all valid:
>
> ```
> $ python example.py --name="Sherrerd Hall" --stories=3 climb_stairs 10
> $ python example.py --name="Sherrerd Hall" climb_stairs --stairs_per_story=10
> $ python example.py --name="Sherrerd Hall" climb_stairs --stairs-per-story 10
> $ python example.py climb-stairs --stairs-per-story 10 --name="Sherrerd Hall"
> ```
>
> You'll notice that hyphens and underscores (`-` and `_`) are interchangeable in member names and flag names.

However, the generated help text does seem to ask for a flag with underscores:

```bsh
> python .\script.py -h
INFO: Showing help with the command 'script.py -- --help'.

NAME
    script.py

SYNOPSIS
    script.py <flags>

FLAGS
    --name_of_cat=NAME_OF_CAT
```

My recommendation is that if you're making a quick script for yourself, Fire is awesome, but if you're making something to be distributed or more complex, it's better to use a more configurable framework, like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) (included in stdlib) or [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) (my personal favorite). [Here](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/benefits.md) is Fire's self-stated list of benefits; if your use case is more complex, another library might be better.

Comment: Yeah, this is it, I just failed at reading docs, I guess this happens ^^ Thank you very much for your answer/time anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `Fire` module but I do have a python command line application where we are using `nameofcat` type syntax. I pass a word with upto 17 aplhabets total in it as argument to script and I do not use any hypen or underscore.